# Password parameters Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to create an validation on my password item how check if the password have the minimal parameters to be a strong password, i usually put

8 characters minimum (1 alphabet 1 number and 1 special character)

i tried a plug-in how do this check for me, but i getting trouble with it, because i use a computation to apply the MD5 Hash code on the intuped pass, avoiding to save the password raw in the bank, but when i submit the page, and the computation do the hash, the plug-in do his validation again and stop to recognize the password and in special the special characters,

I use this plug-in

(http://apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/item-plugin/password-item_204.html )

after that found this bar how do an score and change an display item based on the strength of the password using javascript and html, in both cases i tried to get the logical and apply to an validation (PL/SQL returning in a error text) but i'm no getting any progress, there is another way how can i do that?

https://patelkartik.blogspot.com/2010/10/password-strength-meter-in-apex.html (Site of the bar)

Thank to read til here

My version of apex is the 5.1 and i'm running  the Database 11g XE o the windows

Comment: Have you considered the native feature? https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEADM/configuring-security.htm#GUID-7379B6A1-F546-4DB3-9780-3CEB7F1D5E4C

Comment: If this is for a "Change/Set My Password" type screen, you could use a plugin like this: https://github.com/jeffreykemp/jk64-plugin-passwordstrength